# Image Uneven Falling Motion

Tags: libgdx

My image has to fall down from top to bottom of the screen within 5 seconds. The motion runs smoothly on desktop and my smartphone, but not on my Galaxy Tab S2.

```java
public class MyImage extend Actor {
float fallingSpeed = 0; 

public void act(float delta)
{
    setY(getY() - fallingSpeed * delta);
}

public void setFallingSpeed(float t)
{
    this.fallingSpeed = t;
}
```

- has no fps issue
- tablet has enough memory and ram
- increase of fallingSpeed to GameHeight/2, still give me an uneven motion

When falling with a constant value (1), the animation will become smooth, but i would prefer a way to specify the speed in more definable way like definition of fallingSpeed above, also wants to know the reason for the uneven motion.

gameScreen class codes:

```java
//inside game screen class

float increaseSpeedDuration = 1;// increase falling speed after one second
float increaseSpeedValue = Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/60;
float globalFallingSpeed = Gdx.graphics.getHeight()/5;

private void updateFallingSpeed(float dt) {
        increaseSpeedTimer += dt;
        if(increaseSpeedTimer > increaseSpeedDuration )
        {
            increaseSpeedTimer = 0;
            globalFallingSpeed += increaseSpeedValue;
            myImage.setFallingSpeed(globalFallingSpeed); // setFallingSpeed will change the fallingSpeed value inside my image class.
        }
    }

public void render(float delta)
{
    updateFallingSpeed(delta); 
}
```

Any help?

Comment: What value holds "delta" variable and what is "update method"?

Comment: Sorry for confusing sir. update is a method constantly called inside act. Delta is the parameter from act method. Has edited the displayed codes in a more readable way.

Comment: i dont know why the delta value fluctuate so differently only when i tested with tablet. :(

Comment: How do you calculate GameHeight? is that value from a camera or from Gdx.graphics?

Comment: @LuisFernandoFrontanilla from Gdx.graphics. I realised once i cancel out update for adding speed with time, my image will move smoother. Please see the codes I have updated.

Comment: Are you sure that render() method has that delta parameter? Try getting delta by calling delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

Comment: @MilanG Sorry for late reply. Yes, the render method is from my gameScreen class implements Screen. Have tried Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime() but it shows the same result. Now i change the codes to setY(getY()-fallingSpeed/60f), not sure if it will give me any unexpected consequences.

Comment: What does this line actually say because what you posted won't compile: `
float globalFallingSpeed = Gdx.graphics.getHeight()5;` ?

Comment: @Tenfour04 Sorry for confusing. I have edited my codes. The codes posted are actually a simplify version. Please let me know if you willing to read my full codes for the relevant class.